# Get a list of all playgrounds

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to get a list of all nearby playgrounds. When creating an new place on Google Maps I can select "playground" as category, unfortunately this does not seem to be supported in the API (https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1)

Have I missed something?

Regards
Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there's no type for that in the Google Places API currently.  But you can always fallback to using a query string.

So try `keyword=playground` (for [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)) or `query=playground` (for [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests)) instead.

Comment: that's what I ended doing, but does this also work if you search in other languages?

Comment: Probably not very well, unfortunately :(

Comment: I meant to add, please feel free to file a Feature Request on the Google Places API issue tracker to ask for playground to be added to the supported types: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request